# Best way for super method to cancel child method call

Tags: objective-c, oop, methods, architecture

I have a handful of classes that manage some data. They all sync with a server, and the sync is started by one method called `startSync`. I want the super method to do some checking if the sync is even necessary, and if it isn't to stop the sync before the child method kicks off the sync.

I have thought of a few options, but not sure which one is the best way to implement it. I'm working in Objective-C so that adds a few variables to consider.

A) Make the method return a boolean value and have the child implementation call the super implementation and check the boolean, returning false if it is false. But someone writing a subclass and implementing the method won't always know what to do with that.
B) Make a `doSync` abstract method that the super class calls from the `startSync` method that one would call from outside the class. This has the side effect of not knowing which method to call and accidentially overriding the wrong method.
C) Same as B but the "doSync" method is protected by using an "internal" header. This has the side effect of accidentally overriding the wrong method because they don't know about the internal header, but outside classes don't know about the `doCall` method to skip the check.

What I'm looking for is input on if one of these is the most appropriate or if there is a better option.

Comment: B, then resolve your issues with appropriate documentation.

Comment: Can you explain why you would choose B and not C?

Comment: It wouldn't be 'internal', it would just be specific to subclasses. That's a fine approach, but usually only if you have more than one method...

Comment: So C is only good for multiple methods.. Ok that makes sense.

Comment: Not only, but it's heavy weight for only one method.